# How to get data from <li> elements by clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have a JQuery that records all the immediate parent lists in a cookie when a child list is clicked.

Example -

```
- Parent1  
  - Child1
     - GrandChild1
     - Grandchild2
     - Grandchild3
  - Child2
     - Grandchild4
     - Grandchild5
```

Clicking on `Grandchild2` must record `Parent1, Child1, Grandchild2` in a cookie. However my JQuery code fails to do so.

**JQuery Code -**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('li').click(function() {
                var obj = $(this).parents('li').add(this);
                obj.css('color', 'red');
                var obj1 = $(this).parents('li').data().add(this);
                var data = "data=";
                document.cookie = data+JSON.stringify(obj1);
            });
        });
```

The `'data' cookie` stores `null` and `var obj1 = $(this).parents('li').data().add(this);` throws `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'add' of null`. Where am I going wrong? Kindly help.

Comment: You are misusing many things here.

Comment: @dholakiyaankit >> sure, http://jsfiddle.net/rajarshi/447yE/4/

Comment: @BlackSheep >> Oh, I am new to JQuery. So, I need help.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8XU85/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny >> Thanks. This is exactly what I needed. Can you make that an answer? I'll be glad to mark it as my accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation()
        var x = $(this).parents('li').add(this).map(function () {
            return $.trim(this.firstChild.nodeValue)
        }).get();
        var data = "data=";
        document.cookie = data + x.join();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8XU85/)